# add one gameobject component into another gameobject with values at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At runtime I want to **copy one Gameobject component to another gameobject**.

In my case I have one camera where multiple scripts are added with values settings.

The same components I want to add into my another camera at runtime. I've tried this so far, getting all components of an object then trying to add but it is not working.

```
Component[] components = GameObject.Find("CamFly").GetComponents(typeof(Component));
for(var i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
{
   objCamera.AddComponent<components[i]>();
   ///error in above line said adds a component class named/calss name to the gameobject                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend designing your app so you can call [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com//ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) and get a clone instead. Easier and faster than what you want.
But if you insist, you can use the code from [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458207/copy-a-component-at-runtime.html) on Unity forums.
The reason of the error you get is, you try to add the very same Component (and not a copy of it) to another object, i.e. you want to force the Component to have two parents at the same time, and that's not possible (it's also not possible to "rip it off" from the original parent and hand over to a new one; for 'simulating' that effect, you should also use the code -or similar- I linked).

Comment: I want to add one gameobject components into another gameobject i.e., i use above code.

Comment: Then you should copy-paste the code from the answer (given by Shaffe) I linked. As of your 2nd comment: you clone the GO and what's not working? Your code above will never work (I explained why). By cloning however, the new object will have the same components as the old one does.

Comment: hey mark i tried shaffe code but it is not saving/maintaining the value instead it clone new object

Answer (score 1):

From Mark's answer I found this and it works just as expected and it does copy the field values. Here is the complete code :

```
//Might not work on iOS.
public static T GetCopyOf<T>(this Component comp, T other) where T : Component
{
    Type type = comp.GetType();
    if (type != other.GetType()) return null; // type mis-match
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
    PropertyInfo[] pinfos = type.GetProperties(flags);
    foreach (var pinfo in pinfos)
    {
        if (pinfo.CanWrite)
        {
            try
            {
                pinfo.SetValue(comp, pinfo.GetValue(other, null), null);
            }
            catch { } // In case of NotImplementedException being thrown.
        }
    }
    FieldInfo[] finfos = type.GetFields(flags);
    foreach (var finfo in finfos)
    {
        finfo.SetValue(comp, finfo.GetValue(other));
    }
    return comp as T;
}
public static T AddComponent<T>(this GameObject go, T toAdd) where T : Component
{
    return go.AddComponent<T>().GetCopyOf(toAdd) as T;
}//Example usage  Health myHealth = gameObject.AddComponent<Health>(enemy.health);
```

Comment: He'll try to copy-paste and with zero effort come back with a "this no working". You just waste your time. But thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I know I've tried to help him before. And hey the upvote was for leading me to this nice extension method. I dont need it but its going in the tools class ;)

Comment: Haha, doing just the same thing right now :D Cheers mate! ;)