# Change Component.gameObject, possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

First of all: Yes, I already read [add one gameobject component into another gameobject with values at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069770/add-one-gameobject-component-into-another-gameobject-with-values-at-runtime), but it dosent work/help me with the ParticleSystem components: it will not copy them (wich is an issue)

I have a component of type `ParticleSystem` loaded from my assetbundle, and I need to add another `ParticleSystem` to another `GameObject`. Now, when trying to just write `particleSystem.gameObject = OtherGameObject;` it returns me an error that tells me that Component.gameObject is read only. Now, the reason of why I want to change the .gameObject property is because I made a particle in Unity and creating it via code would take forever + you already can copy/paste a component in Unity, so why not do it, only via code?

Anyways I really need to find a way to add my component, loaded from an assetbundle, to another GameObject. Not as child of the GameObject (so directly forget pls the Object.Instantiate methot), it needs to be attached to my GameObject itself, not to be a child of it. Or if that‘s impossible, is there anyway to copy a Component and directly attaching it to a GameObject?

If something isn‘t clear then you can tell it me

Comment: See the duplicate link .. for Unity components this might fail though in some (many?) cases .. in general you would use `AddComponent` and then pass on the values of relevant properties

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say `I have a specific particle and reproducing it via code would take forever`? The question is a bit hazy - every game object is simply a container that represents something in your game.. you can't make a disparate type replace your gameobject, but you can inherit from it.

Comment: If you want to copy a component and attach to a gameobject, that's what `Instantiate` is for. It will still be a child though - is there a big issue with making it a child?

Comment: no you cant do this but you can create a child for your object add particleSystem component to that and when you wish to change particleSystem object set that parent to other object and rest the transform.postion of game object that have particleSystem